# How do i show image on notification bar when push comes from FCM?

Tags: objective-c

I have tried using NotificationServiceExtension,but didn't got proper tutorial in objective-c to achieve that.
Process:- I create a NotificationServiceExtension in that i wrote a code which accepts media urls.then i create app groups.
Payload which is coming from backend:

```
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        body = Test;
        title = Test;
    };
    badge = 1;
    "content-available" = 1;
};
badge = 1;
body = Test;
"gcm.message_id" = "0:1511437914514%a62432a6262432";
"gcm.notification.alert" = "";
"gcm.notification.id" = "";
"gcm.notification.location_ids" = "";
"gcm.notification.main_picture" = "somelink/logo-big.png";
"gcm.notification.notification_type" = Generic;
icon = "";
id = "";
"location_ids" = "";
"main_picture" = "somelink/logo-big.png";
"notification_type" = Generic;
title = Test;
```

Comment: Post some more info about what you tried

Comment: @alseether is it fine or shall i elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the app icon when the push notification comes, you need to add the AppIcon under the Images.xcassets folder of your app.

Comment: No, I want to show images which comes from web service on push.Like i said before,i am getting media url in payload but unable to show image on push bar (Objective c)